# How to Hide and Unhide Column with Custom Menu in Google Sheets using Google Script

Tags: java, user-interface, google-sheets, toggle

I would like to "TOGGLE" between two functions (hide & unhide of a specific column - allocated to a specific month), by clicking on a custom item (monthName) in a menu that I created in Google Sheets (using the Ui).

Currently only the first function (hiding of a column) works. The second function (unhiding that same column), does not work.

Would you please be so kind to help.

Here follows the code:

---

```
var month = "Month-YY";

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

   ui.createMenu('Show/Hide Columns')
     .addItem(month, 'toggleMonth')
     .addToUi();
};

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
var count = 0;


function toggleMonth() {


    count++;
    var isEven = function(someNumber) {
        return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
    };
    if (isEven(count) === false) {
        sh.hideColumns(2, 3)
    } else if (isEven(count) === true) {
        sh.unhideColumn(sh.getRange('B:D'))
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.